# Get number of rows from .csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am writing a Python module where I read a .csv file with 2 columns and a random amount of rows. I then go through these rows until column 1 > x. At this point I need the data from the current row and the previous row to do some calculations.

Currently, I am using 'for i in range(rows)' but each csv file will have a different amount of rows so this wont work.

The code can be seen below:

```
rows = 73
    for i in range(rows):  

        c_level = Strapping_Table[Tank_Number][i,0]  # Current level
        c_volume = Strapping_Table[Tank_Number][i,1] # Current volume

        if c_level > level:

            p_level = Strapping_Table[Tank_Number][i-1,0]    # Previous level
            p_volume = Strapping_Table[Tank_Number][i-1,1]  # Previous volume

            x = level - p_level   # Intermediate values
            if x < 0:
                x = 0
            y = c_level - p_level
            z = c_volume - p_volume

            volume = p_volume + ((x / y) * z)

            return volume
```

When playing around with arrays, I used:

```
for row in Tank_data: 
   print row[c]       # print column c
   time.sleep(1)
```

This goes through all the rows, but I cannot access the previous rows data with this method.

I have thought about storing previous row and current row in every loop, but before I do this I was wondering if there is a simple way to get the amount of rows in a csv.

Comment: The indexing `Strapping_Table[Tank_Number][i,0]` suggests that you have already loaded this as a `numpy` array or `pandas` dataframe.  `[i,0]` is not Python list or string indexing.  Give us more information on this `Strapping_table` object - type, shape, dtype.  If this is already loaded then this isn't a `csv` problem; it's array one.

Comment: If you have already loaded the data into an array, you don't have to guess at its size.  `arr.shape[0]` is the number of 'rows' in a 2d array.  And you can probably do this calculation without a loop - just a couple of array operations.  But we need more details.

Comment: Sorry, yes I  was getting confused. I did already convert it into an array using `genfromtxt` from `numpy`.  `arr.shape[0]` would have been useful but I ended up just storing the previous line and current line simultaneously.  
However, `arr.shape` should help me with some other modules I am developing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the previous line

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as file:
     previous_line = next(file)
     for line in file:
        print(previous_line, line)
        previous_line = line
```

Or you can use it with generators

```
def prev_curr(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as file:
        previous_line = next(file)
        for line in file:
            yield previous_line ,line
            previous_line = line
# usage
for prev, curr in prev_curr("myfile"):
    do_your_thing()
```

Comment: I am unsure how enumerate would help here. I understand that it will basically create an index for each row from 0 to n. But how would I use this index to then access the previous row? Like so:  
`current_level = row[0]  
previous_level=row[i-1][0]`  
    
I know that doesn't work but I am unsure how to get it working. If it's not possible I will change the code to store the current and previous line simultaneously. Thanks

Comment: my bad ! See the update now, i think it's the only good way to do it because python Iterators only go forward.

Comment: I ended up doing it by storing the previous line, then when the correct row is reached, the current line is updated whilst the previous line stays as is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `enumerate`.

```
for i, row in enumerate(tank_data): 
   print row[c], tank_data[i-1][c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the size of each row in the csv is unknown until it's read, you'll have to do an intial pass through if you want to find the number of rows, e.g.:

`numberOfRows = (1 for row in file)`

However that would mean your code will read the csv twice, which if it's very big you may not want to do - the simple option of storing the previous row into a global variable each iteration may be the best option in that case.

An alternate route could be to just read in the file and analyse it from that from e.g. a panda DataFrame (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
but again this could lead to slowness if your csv is too big.